# ExactTarget - How to post a record to a data extension that has no primary key?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest, data, extension, post

I have a data extension with the following fields:

- recordId - number
- recordKey - text - length: 50
- recordValue - text - length: 50

None of the above fields are primary key, because they can occur multiple times. My problem is that I wasn't able to construct such a HTTP REST request that would have worked without primary keys: ET always returned with HTTP 404 Not found. As soon as I make one of the fields, I could make it work - but I don't need any primary keys, actually.

On a related note, I could make 2 fields primary key: recordId and recordKey. But then comes my other problem: how to construct such an HTTP request that operates with both fields as primary keys. If I specify both fields in 'keys' JSON field, ET returns with HTTP 400 Bad syntax.

Finally, it's important for us to use REST in favor of SOAP. Plus, we always insert, not update.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please post some of your rest calls so we can emulate this exactly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make the data extension a non-sendable DE and that would remove the requirement for SubscriberKey?